# HtmlHelper missing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an Html Helper, by creating a static class as follows:

```
public static string Crumbs(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] args) where T : class
{
    // ... rest of code goes here.
}
```

And I'm invoking it like this:

```
<% Html.Crumbs(
    Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"),
    Html.ActionLink("Lists", "Index", "User"),
    Html.Encode(Model.List.Name)); %>
```

However, the view does not compile, as I get the following compilation error:

> CS1061:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Crumbs' and no extension method
>   'Crumbs' accepting a first argument of
>   type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I don't get it. None of the documentation that I have mentions that you need to register the namespace of the static class anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import the namespace of your extension in you view or in web.config.

In web.config:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyExtensions.Namespace"/>
```

In your view:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyExtensions.Namespace" %>
```

Comment: Great! I like that fact that you pointed out the two possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the namespace in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="X.Y.Z"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put your helper in namespace (any) that is referenced in web.config or the page itself (Import Namespace).